# getting the server response caused by ajax POST method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to send POST data to the server. This is the ajax code that I use. On the other side I use mySQL and PHP. How can I see what the `insertToDB.php` output was? Currently my code is not working and I am not sure why. Getting the output from `insertToDB.php` is probably the best way to start.

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "insertToDB.php",
       type: 'POST',
        data: {'lastname':'Cena','name':'John', 'email':'jc@gmail.com'},
       success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
        }
     });
```

on the PHP side I have:

```
require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die($conn->connect_error);
}


$url = $_POST["lastname"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];


$query = "INSERT INTO testtable (url ,name ,email) VALUES ('$url',  '$name',  '$email')";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result){
    die ("QUERY FAILED");
}
```

Comment: use `echo` or `die()` with connection, INSERT, UPDATE and all your queries.

Comment: I added the PHP code.

Comment: Just add `echo "data inserted";` after last line and in ajax success `console.log(response)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The first argument to the `success` function is the output](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

That is, if you `console.log(response)` instead of `console.log("success")`, you'll see whatever the server wrote back to the response stream.

(If you're talking about log output on the server side, that's an entirely different matter. Then we'll need to see your serverside code, not the AJAX call.)

Comment: thanks man. I can now see the error. It says: Class 'mysqli' not found in path/..../insertToDB.php. Apparently mySQL is not installed although, i created by table on the server using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

Usee echo and exit in insertToDB.php

and then

console.log(response);

Answer (score 0):

Just handle your db queries, errors and status using `echo` or `die()` and be ware to handle final outputs sent to ajax.

```
echo "Data inserted";
// or 
die("faild");
```

From Ajax

```
success: function(response){console.log(response)};
```